# Cannot connect to Hangouts with Jabber

Tags: jabber

I am trying to use Jabber to connect to Google Hangouts.

My configuration looks like this:

```
(setq jabber-account-list '(("[myusername]@gmail.com"
                             (:network-server . "talk.google.com")
                             (:connection-type . ssl))))
```

When I invoke `jabber-connect-all` and type in my password, I get the following error message:

```
[myusername]@gmail.com: connection lost: `exited abnormally with code 1'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use `starttls` instead. I use it and it works for me.

```
(setq jabber-account-list '(("USERNAME@gmail.com/emacs"
                             (:password . ".....")
                             (:network-server . "talk.google.com")
                             (:connection-type . starttls)
                             )))
```

I also had to go into my account settings and set up a special password for jabber, but that's because I use 2-factor authentication with Google. When you use 2-factor authentication, your regular password does not work for connecting.

Note that this won't let you do group chats (and obviously not calls), but regular chatting should work.

Comment: Ah, what a shame; group chat was what I was most hoping for. Still, thank you for your answer!