# Chatting on Hangouts with Emacs

Tags: integration

[This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13717/cannot-connect-to-hangouts-with-jabber) asks how to connect to Google Hangouts with Jabber specifically, but I want to un-XY it.

Google has dropped support for XMPP and switched to [a proprietary protocol](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/). Is there an existing package or combination of packages that allows Emacs to communicate through this protocol?

Comment: That API is for video calls, I'm not completely convinced yet that their chat has dropped support for jabber.

Comment: I just tested, and jabber [works fine for me](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13732/50). See if that answer I provided works for you. If so I'll close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Well... XMPP is still available, but not 100% compatible with Hangouts. In addition to Video, group chats with XMPP work differently than group chats with hangouts, and if you have a group hangout you won't be able to use it via an XMPP client. Also when you're chatting using an XMPP client, conversation logs are stored differently. So you *can* use XMPP still if you only ever chat 1:1 or everyone you group chat with is using XMPP clients or has "revert to old chat" set in GMail.

More details are here: https://bitbucket.org/EionRobb/purple-hangouts

Comment: There some client https://github.com/tdryer/hangups

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Hangups.el](https://github.com/jtamagnan/hangups.el) which use [hangups_cli](https://github.com/jtamagnan/hangups_cli) python client.